# Windows7 run as admin with password

Tags: windows-7, uac

I love running as a standard user for its security pluses, my admin account is password protected.

The problem appears when I need to run a program that requires admin rights, is there a way to include the password somehow so I won't have to type it every time ? Without changing my current setup: admin password protected account and I log on to a limited standard user account.

I'm thinking of a script or something like that ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what UAC does for you. When you log in to your machine using an account that is in the Administrators group, everything you launch runs as standard user unless you launch it elevated. When you launch it elevated you need only click your consent, you don't need to provide a password.

Logging on to a standard user account doesn't give you more protection, and makes you type the password when you elevate.

Comment: that's not what they say: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Why-use-a-standard-user-account-instead-of-an-administrator-account

Comment: Well technically some people feel more protected typing a password than clicking Yes. Also there is a difference between "an account in the Administrators group" and the Administrator account. Plus UAC can be turned down (or even off) while logging in as standard user guarantees you will only do standard user things.

Developers generally do need to be administrators. They need to install the things they're writing in order to test them. UAC protects you from accidentally using that admin power when you didn't need to.

Comment: Most of my dev tools work just fine, ruby, rails, e-texteditor, except wamp and some system apps. 
The point is, I want to keep my OS as secure as I can, I'm not installing apps or configuring my PC daily, I'm only developing on it.
Also, without a password a virus or trojan could easily bypass that, I'm guessing.

Comment: Nope, the virus or trojan would still need you to click your consent on the UAC prompt. Whether you click that you are ok with it or type a password that you are ok with it, there is still an approval step required.

Comment: I'm thinking that the button click can be emulated sometime in the future, ergo having a password in there might keep things more secure...

Comment: @dakull: That's why it's on a secure desktop (the dark grayed background screen). This stops anything trying to automate them.